# 404 When Creating github_repository_webhook with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-github

We upgraded to using the `integrations/github` provider source and ever since we have started getting a 404 when attempting to create a github_repository_webhook with Terraform. I believe we have all of the necessary pieces required based on the docs, but the API uri in the logs is missing the org. NOTE: Real org and repo names have been redacted.

main.tf

```
resource "aws_codepipeline_webhook" "codepipeline_webhook" {
  name            = "test-github-webhook"
  authentication  = "GITHUB_HMAC"
  target_action   = "CC"
  target_pipeline = aws_codepipeline.pipeline.name

  authentication_configuration {
    secret_token = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.github_token.secret_string
  }

  filter {
    json_path    = "$.ref"
    match_equals = "refs/heads/{Branch}"
  }

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name = "test-github-webhook"
  })
}

# Wire the CodePipeline webhook into a GitHub repository.
resource "github_repository_webhook" "github_webhook" {
  repository = "my_repo"

  configuration {
    url          = aws_codepipeline_webhook.codepipeline_webhook.url
    content_type = "json"
    insecure_ssl = true
    secret       = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.github_token.secret_string
  }

  events = ["push"]
}
```

backend.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.65.0"
    }
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "github" {
  token    = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.github_token.secret_string
  owner    = "my_org"
  base_url = "https://github.com/my_org/" # we have github enterprise
}
```

Error on create:

```
Error: POST https://api.github.com/repos//my_repo/hooks: 404 Not Found []
```

Note that the org is missing completely from the URL. I've also tried including the org name in the github_repository_webhook resource, but the url still comes out with a double slash and a 404:

```
Error: POST https://api.github.com/repos//my_org/my_repo/hooks: 404 Not Found []
```

When I remove the provider source and version completely, terraform falls back to the `hashicorp/terraform` source and the webhook creates without any issues. Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You've probably solved this by now, but just in case there are any others who run into this problem.

*This solution assumes you're using Terraform version >=0.13 and the new Terraform GitHub Integration.*

Check to make sure that all modules that use the `github` provider have defined a `github` `required_providers` block. [If this block is not defined within the module, then it seems that the (deprecated) "hashicorp/github" provider is used](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/655#issuecomment-1032912013) even if you've configured this block on the root module where you've defined the `github` provider. (This is what was causing the error for me.) That is, make sure you've defined the following in each of your modules:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming you've done the above, then try [double checking that you've set up the GitHub integration properly](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs). Some notable gotchas are:

- When upgrading from `hashicorp/github` to `integrations/github`, use `terraform state replace-provider`. Otherwise, Terraform will still require the old provider to interact with the state file.
- The `organization` argument has been deprecated in favor of the `owner` argument (should behave the same in the mean time, but just in case).

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of `terraform providers`?
I suspect you have both versions of the github provider in your state.
If you do,

`terraform state replace-provider hashicorp/github integrations/github`
Should fix you up.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a few months ago. Your url is missing the organization. It should be of the format

`https://api.github.com/repos/my_organization/my_repo/hooks`